# Get All Configuration Files Across Application

Tags: c#, reflection, .net

I have a modularized application where each module is it's own project. Each module can then be packaged into a single dll.

I have added my own custom configuration file for each module called "Scripts.config" within the root of the project. I was wondering if there was a way to get all the Scripts.config files in the application.

The following code is used to get all implementations of a particular type:

```
private IList<Type> GetTypes<T>() {
    return BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract)).ToList();
}
```

I guess i'm looking for the equivalent but to get all the "Script.config" files. I guess I could embed the Scripts.config file but I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Sorry if I haven't explained this clearly. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I'd go for embedding too.

Comment: Thanks that's the way I'm leaning. This is what I already do to grab images across the modules. However I was just wondering if it should be treated differently because it's a .config file.

Comment: Well I guess you could try adding each module's script.config file to your main application, but using 'Add As Link' instead of Add, but I've not tried that myself with config files.

Comment: It looks like embedding is the way to go then. I'll leave this open for abit incase anyone with other ideas comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought embedding the resource was the best way to go. I simply get the required assemblies and then use the following code for each assembly to retrieve the content of the Scripts.config file.

```
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Single(n => n.EndsWith("Scripts.config")))) {
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
}
```